# Log Analytics Workspace: Logs Ingestion API with python script hosted on a Linux server

Tags: python, azure, azure-log-analytics

I have a Python script that I want to run daily that produces a Pandas dataframe.

I want this dataframe to be added daily to my log analytics workspace.

I have a Linux server that I can use to run my Python script.

What do I need to do to make this work using
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-ingestion-api-overview#rest-api-call

Is there a minimal reproducible example available?

Comment: What is the code you have used, I am unable to find in that doc? Why cant you simply use an azure function for this which runs on Linyx server, You send the input body to http trigger using requests. In http trigger you can use the **code** which you havent mentioned

Comment: Can i get a minimal reproducible example on how to do what you've mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to send data frame to Log Analytics Workspace and I have followed [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77263051/azure-log-analytics-how-to-send-custom-python-pandas-dataframes-into-law/77263488#77263488):

Firstly created a [function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators) in Local in VS code:

**`__init__.py:`**

```
import logging
import requests
import datetime
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd

logtype2="RithwikLogs"
def rith_build_signature(customer_id, shared_key, date, content_length, method, content_type, resource):
    x_headers = 'x-ms-date:' + date
    string_to_hash = method + "\n" + str(content_length) + "\n" + content_type + "\n" + x_headers + "\n" + resource
    bytes_to_hash = bytes(string_to_hash, encoding="utf-8")  
    decoded_key = base64.b64decode(shared_key)
    encoded_hash = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(decoded_key, bytes_to_hash, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
    authorization = "SharedKey {}:{}".format(customer_id,encoded_hash)
    return authorization
def post_data1(customer_id, shared_key, body, log_type):
    method = 'POST'
    content_type = 'application/json'
    resource = '/api/logs'
    rfc1123date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
    content_length = len(body)
    signature = rith_build_signature(customer_id, shared_key, rfc1123date, content_length, method, content_type, resource)
    uri = 'https://' + customer_id + '.ods.opinsights.azure.com' + resource + '?api-version=2016-04-01'

    headers = {
        'content-type': content_type,
        'Authorization': signature,
        'Log-Type': log_type,
        'x-ms-date': rfc1123date
    }

    response = requests.post(uri,data=body, headers=headers)
    if (response.status_code >= 200 and response.status_code <= 299):
        print('Rithwik Bojja Data Frame is sent, Go and check')
    else:
        print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))

rithwik_data1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Bojja', 'Rithwik', 'Chotu'],
    'Age': [8, 8008, 24]
})

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    post_data1('Workspaceid', 'Primary key',rithwik_data1.to_json(orient="records"), logtype2)
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello Rithwik Bojja Sent Data Successfully.")
```

Here given data frame in code directly, you can send the data frame to trigger in the body of the trigger while calling it(POST).

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "con",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

**`host.json:`**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**`function.json:`**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`requirements.txt:`**

```
azure-functions
requests
pandas
```

Now deployed my function app to azure.

**`Output:`**

Now executed it:

[image]

Log Analytics Workspace:

[image]

[image]